# I lost my Space Core, how do I get it back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Inside a cave, I used Infernal Blast (from the Midas Magic mod) and he just disappeared. I used the `tcl` (or noclip) command to fly around looking for it, but no luck. I tried to look up the ID for the Space Core to spawn a new one, but none I've found so far have worked. What should I do? Does it respawn at the same location?

Answer (score 2):

The [Space Core link on the wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Space_Core#Space_Core)  has the ID you need.

The first to signs are 'xx' though and have to be replaced by the corrosponding load order digits. These can be found by counting the place of the mod in the esp load list. The first will be skyrim.esm (00) and counting on from there the next three would be 01, 02 and 03. This system is [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) however! So the eleventh item in the list is not 10 but 0a. If the core mod would be third, then the ID would be 02000d62 for example.

I hope this helps you!